# How to store \sqrt to a macro using \xdef

Tags: errors

I apologize if this is a trivial question but I am fairly novice with latex. I have been trying to save several math expressions to a variable using `\xdef` (within a loop, but that is not the issue here). It seems that I can store any math expression to a variable using `\xdef` but I cannot store any expression that contains `\sqrt`. For example in the following program:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\xdef\TestFun{e^{x+1}}
$\TestFun$
\xdef\TestFunA{{\sqrt{x+1}}}
$\TestFunA$
\end{document}
```

`$TestFun$` works and prints what is expected, while When I run the `\TestFunA`, I get the following error message:

```
 l.14 \xdef\TestFun{\sqrt
                        {x+1}}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
```

Any ideas as to how to make this work it will be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

My goal is to loop over a list of functions to create a linear combination of the functions. If it helps, the complete loop code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\readlist\FUNS{X,X^2,e^{x+1},\sqrt{X}}

\xdef\SUMFUNS{\FUNS[1]}
\foreach \x in {2,...,\FUNSlen} {
\xdef\SUMFUNS{\SUMFUNS+{\noexpand\FUNS[\x]}}
}
$\SUMFUNS$
\end{document}
```

I used @clemens suggestion, and it currently does what I want it to do, but only if the `\sqrt` function is the last on the list, which is not a big price to pay for me. But, I will welcome any improvements!

Comment: Because `\sqrt` is not expandable.  So `\edef` and `\xdef` (which is a global `\edef`) is out.  There is `\def` and `\gdef` (global `\def`) as alternatives that do not expand.  Or else you could use `\protected@edef` (after `\makeatletter` has been invoked)

Comment: `\xdef\TestFunA{{\noexpand\sqrt{x+1}}}`

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  to properly format a code block, highlight it, then click on the `{}` icon above the question box.  for a short in-line string, wrap it in backticks.

Comment: Thanks all!  clemens suggestion worked like magic.  @ barbara beeton will do in the future!

Comment: there is a reason that `\xdef` is not a documented latex command, you can not put most latex commands into its argument.

Comment: Why don’t you simply say `\newcommand*{\myformula}{\sqrt{x+1}}`?

Comment: This is readily solved using `\def` or, better, `\newcommand`. You probably should show what kind of loop you're trying to use to make the problem more sensible.

Comment: @ egreg: I modified the question to show the complete loop. I hope the addition makes it clear.

Comment: How about using `X^{1/2}` instead of `\sqrt{X}`?

Comment: Babis, when you want to ping a user I don't think you can have a space between the at-sign and the username, so you should write e.g. @egreg.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to build the linear combination, you might try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\readlist\FUNS{X,X^2,e^{X+1},\sqrt{X},X^{1/2},X}

$\foreachitem\i\in\FUNS{\ifnum\icnt>1\relax+\else\fi{\i}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, that does not address the question raised in the title.

Comment: Less typing" `$\foreachitem\i\in\FUNS{\ifnum\icnt=1\else+\fi\i}$`.  Also, no `pgffor` required.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\xdef` is dangerous and expansion should be limited to the desired level. In your case, you need to expand once `\SUMFUNS` and twice `\FUNS[\x]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\providecommand\expandonce{% etoolbox has it
  \unexpanded\expandafter
}
\newcommand\expandtwice{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
}

\begin{document}

\readlist\FUNS{X,X^2,e^{x+1},\sqrt{X}}

\xdef\SUMFUNS{\expandtwice{\FUNS[1]}}
\foreach \x in {2,...,\FUNSlen} {%
  \xdef\SUMFUNS{%
    \expandonce{\SUMFUNS}+\expandtwice{\FUNS[\x]}%
  }%
}

$\SUMFUNS$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler approach with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_babis_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_babis_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sumlist}{m}
 {
  \clist_use:cn { l_babis_list_#1_clist } { + }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\definelist{FUNS}{X,X^2,e^{x+1},\sqrt{X}}

$\sumlist{FUNS}$

\end{document}
```